# Generating a jar and using it as dependency in another module

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, maven-dependency-plugin

I have multiple modules in a single project. I have packaged a module as jar and included it as a dependency in another module. I want this jar to be generated and installed in a specific folder.

**Dependency of module A included in B**

**Specifying the folder to copy the jar**

```xml
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <includeArtifactIds>
                    <artifactId>rpgenerator</artifactId>
                </includeArtifactIds>
                <includeGroupIds>
                    <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
                </includeGroupIds>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/reports/</outputDirectory>

            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**But I do not see the jar in the folder B.reports.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get in the log?

Comment: I do not get any error. The jar is not generated in output directory

Comment: Then add the complete output log to the question.